# Consulta Obtener valores de un modelo A apatir del modelo B

Tags: laravel-8

Estoy haciendo un filtro para el buscador en una sección tengo:
tabla A y tabla B relacionadas por 1 a n.
tabla A -> A_id(Primary)...
tabla B->B_id(Primary),A_id(foreing),clienteId(foreing)...

Accedo desde la tabla A a los datos de la tabla B mediante el modelo por lo que estoy obligado a usar el modelo y no puedo usar un db::table por que tengo toda la funcionabilidad implementada y tendría que rehacerla.

El filtro para el buscador se basa en buscar en la tabla B registros que coincidan con el id que le paso y buscarían en la columna de clienteId para que me devuelva la info de la tabla A

Entonces uso esa  consulta para buscar en la tabla B y que me devuelva el modelo relacionado con la tabla A de tal forma que si el cliente esta en dos filas de la tabla A me devuelva esas filas.

```
$consulta=A::where('A_id', function($consulta) use($request) {  $consulta->select('A_id')->from('B')->where('cliente_id', $request->cliente )->first();} )->paginate($this->numeroRegistrosPagina);
```

Actualmente esta consulta da un fallo si quitas first() da un error cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
por que la subconsulta devuelve mas de una fila y es normal puesto que los clientes puede estar en mas de una fila de la tabla A.
¿Entonces de que forma puedo arreglar esto ?, se puede usar el modelo B puesto que también tiene la id de la tabla A.

Gracias a todos

Comment: En realidad no hay nada que impida que hagas raw selects, el que tengas las relaciones en los modelos no te lo impide, de todas formas, lo ideal seria que muestres que error tienes, o un poco mas de codigo de lo que estas haciendo para que se comprenda mejor el contexto.

Comment: acabo de actualizarlo por si te interesa

Comment: ¿Estas usando Livewire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede obtener sin problemas los datos del modelo A, desde el modelo B, con la implementación del método de relación correspondiente, por ejemplo;

```
    <?php
     
    namespace App\Models;
     
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
     
    class B extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Obtiene los datos de A, desde B.
         */
        public function relacionConA()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(A::class);
        }
...
```

Y al seleccionar un objeto del modelo B, ya tenes los datos de A;

```
$datoA = B::where('campo','like', '%'.$busqueda.'%')->relacionConA->nombreColumnaModeloA;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, llegue a esta misma conclusión que tu propones y hice los cambios pertinentes para que funcionara y blade no chillara mucho pues antes usaba solo el modelo de la tabla A.

Comment: @MiguelAngelBlancoGonzalez cuando alguien contesta tu preguntas y satisface tus necesidades recuerda marcarlas como resueltas ... eso te dara puntaje a ti y a la persona en reputación para desbloquear cosas mas adelante...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tengo que hacer algo mas para cerrar la pregunta

Comment: no, con esto tu pregunta esta correctamente y otros podrán tambien beneficiarse.